# uWSGI - "Out of memory: Kill process"

Tags: centos, python, nginx, uwsgi

The following problem is happening with my uWSGI (a Pyramid app) ...

```
Out of memory: Kill process 17715 (uwsgi) score 299 or sacrifice child
Killed process 17715, UID 0, (uwsgi) total-vm:2731232kB, anon-rss:790924kB, file -rss:576kB
```

[image]

This message is displayed on the CentOS 7 server login screen.

Is there any way to control memory consumption in uWSGI? Examples: "consume up to 60% of available memory", "consume up to 2GBs", etc...

I would like something that is controlled by uWSGI itself.

I searched if there was any option in the uWSGI itself to control this memory consumption... but nothing found...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 uses systemd, so the most logical approach is to override/extend the uwsgi unit file with a `MemoryLimit` option.  You can read more about that [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/resources.html).